# How to split strings at the end of last letter?

Tags: r, cpu-word, strsplit

Could you please show me how to split strings at the end of last letter? I have some data read from xlsx. Please take a look from the pic. The strings consists of a english word and some other character (could be number or ?,!, etc). There is probably space between word and other character or not.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "bananas1"
"insurance?"
"town!"
"hostel 4"
"qualifications 5"
"labor-consuming 6"
"problem solving 7"

Comment: Thank you Mark Keen. But there are lots of other characters following words. So it's better split strings at the end of last letter.

Comment: Please put all the important information in the question. You can edit your question by clicking `edit` under the tags. Once you've done that, you can delete those comments

Comment: Since there isn't a simple thing to split on, you're going to want to use `regular expressions` to grab the 2 parts of your strings. Search for a tutorial on `regular expressions` or `regex` for short and use https://regex101.com to test out your expressions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the last character only, you could try the following strategy using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("bananas1", "insurance?", "town!", "hostel 4", "qualifications 5", "labor-consuming 6", "problem solving 7")

map2_chr(x, (str_length(x) ), ~str_sub(.x, .y, .y))
```